# How do I implement a dapp browser in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ethereum, decentralized-applications, web3dart

I have tired to months to inject window.ethereum in flutter webview but to no avail, i found out i can only inject javascript on page load end, but once the page have loaded finished, window.ethereum would not be available to the dapp, is there any way i can inject window.ethereum on page start...

what i have tried

````dart
WebView(
                navigationDelegate: (action) {
                  if (action.isForMainFrame) {
                    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  }
                  return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                },
                onProgress: (precent) {
                  setState(() {
                    browserLoadingPercent = precent / 100;
                  });
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  _controller = controller;
                },
                initialUrl: widget.data ?? dappBrowserInitialUrl,
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                onPageStarted: (url) async {
                  dappBrowser.text = url;
                  if (urlLoaded == '') {
                    urlLoaded = url;
                  }
                },
                onPageFinished: (url) async {
                  return;
                  try {
                    if (urlLoaded == '') {
                      return;
                    } else {
                      urlLoaded = '';
                    }
                    await _controller.runJavascript(widget.sweetAlert);
                    await _controller.runJavascript(widget.web3);
                    await _controller.runJavascript(widget.provider);

                    var favicon =
                        await _controller.runJavascriptReturningResult('''
                        var getFavicon = function(){
                            var favicon = undefined;
                            var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
                            for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
                            {
                                if((nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "icon")||(nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "shortcut icon"))
                                {
                                    favicon = nodeList[i].getAttribute("href");

                                }
                            }

                            return new URL(favicon, document.baseURI).href;        
                        }

                        getFavicon();
                        ''');

                    favicon = favicon.split('"').join('').split("'").join('');
                    await showDialog(
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (_) {
                        return SimpleDialog(
                          title: Column(
                            children: [
                              if (true)
                                Container(
                                  height: 100.0,
                                  width: 100.0,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                                  child: Image.network(favicon),
                                ),
                              Text(url),
                            ],
                          ),
                          contentPadding:
                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 16.0),
                          children: [
                            if (url.isNotEmpty)
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                                child: Text('Connection to ${url}'),
                              ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      primary: Colors.white,
                                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .secondary,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      showDialog(
                                          barrierDismissible: false,
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (context) {
                                            var ethEnabledBlockChain =
                                                <Widget>[];
                                            for (String i
                                                in getBlockChains().keys) {
                                              ethEnabledBlockChain.add(InkWell(
                                                onTap: () async {
                                                  var count = 0;
                                                  var seedPhrase =
                                                      (await SharedPreferences
                                                              .getInstance())
                                                          .getString(
                                                              'mmemomic');
                                                  await _controller
                                                      .runJavascript('''
                                                        window.web3 = new Web3(
                                                                new HDWalletProvider({
                                                                  mnemonic: {
                                                                    phrase:
                                                                      "${seedPhrase}",
                                                                  },
                                                                  providerOrUrl: "${getBlockChains()[i]['rpc']}",
                                                                  chainId: ${getBlockChains()[i]['chainId']},
                                                                })
                                                              );
                                                        ''');
                                                  Navigator.popUntil(context,
                                                      (route) {
                                                    return count++ == 2;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                                child: buildRow(
                                                    getBlockChains()[i]
                                                                ['image'] !=
                                                            null
                                                        ? getBlockChains()[i]
                                                            ['image']
                                                        : 'assets/ethereum_logo.png',
                                                    i),
                                              ));
                                            }
                                            return Dialog(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            40)),
                                                elevation: 16,
                                                child: Container(
                                                  child: ListView(
                                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                                                      Center(
                                                          child: Text(
                                                              'Select BlockChains')),
                                                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                                                    ]..addAll(
                                                        ethEnabledBlockChain),
                                                  ),
                                                ));
                                          });
                                    },
                                    child: Text('APPROVE'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      primary: Colors.white,
                                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .secondary,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                    child: Text('REJECT'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );

                    // await _controller.runJavascript(
                    //     'document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML');
                    // await _controller.runJavascript(widget.reEnableJavascript);
                    // await _controller.runJavascript('''
                    // var load_event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    // load_event.initEvent("DOMContentLoaded", true, true);
                    // window.document.dispatchEvent(load_event);
                    // ''');
                    // await _controller.runJavascript('''
                    //   var load_event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    //   load_event.initEvent("load", true, true);
                    //   window.document.dispatchEvent(load_event);
                    //   ''');

                    await _controller.runJavascript('''
                    (async function () {
                            const account = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];
                            console.log('web3 dapp browser: ' + account);
                    })();''');

                    print('end of function');
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                gestureRecognizers: gestureRecognizers,
              )```
````

Comment: Did you come up with a solution by any chance?

Comment: Yes...done and ready ould send in the code

Comment: @DavyKing, If you have a solution then can you post here your answer? I'm also facing the same issue while connecting the wallet to WebView of flutter.

Comment: Message me on telegram @im_davyking

Answer (score -2):

Embedded dApp browser is an antipattern in Web3 design for mobile apps.

[Instead, you should use WalletConnect protocol if you want to have Ethereum transaction capabilities on your mobile apps](https://walletconnect.com/).

Comment: I really need it...if you can help me with step...I want to build a browser like trust wallet,and not all dapp uses walletconnect